# Breakdown of どうなってる

Tags: grammar, definitions

> 西洋は**どうなってる**？

Is どうなってる itself a phrase meaning 'how is it?' or a combination of several meanings? Such as どう, なる and ている.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your interpretation.

Comment: Will you explain what you try to mean by the word "breakdown". To me, **although it looks like to me only**, **breaking down = breaking down into the parts of speech** seems to learners "too hard to understand".

Comment: It sounds like they're asking whether it's compositional in terms of meaning, not what classes the words belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a single phrase, consisting of the three words you found.
But it's still a whole phrase with many different ways to make use of.

Here are some examples.
You meet a friend and he acts totally weird. Then you would think:

> いったいどうなって(る)んだ、こいつは？

Or you think of your sister, who has moved to Canada and you didn't hear from her for quite some time. You start worrying.

> XX(name)はどうなってるのかな〜

Comment: "consisting of the three words" >> Were you taught that ている was a single word?

Comment: @choco wouldn't the three words be どう, なって, and (い)る?

Comment: I thought shavasadhana was referring to "どう, なる and ている" by "the three words **you found**." I think you'd say it's どう+なって(te-form of verb なる)+いる(補助動詞). (I would be more inclined to split it to どう+なっ(連用形 of verb なる)+て(接続助詞)+いる(補助動詞), though.)